# Android Media player getting null pointer exception while trying to pause(Playing via Service)

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, mp3

//This is the Code for my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {


    MediaPlayer media;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        stopService(intent);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {
            media.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        media.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//        media.stop();
        media.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void dataParse(String value){
        if(value.equals(R.string.play)){
            media.start();
        }else  if(value.equals("pause")) {
            media.pause();
        }else {
            media.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

//The click event where starting the service.

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(tv.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.play))){
                    startService(intent);
                    tv.setText(R.string.pause);
                }else  if(tv.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.pause))){
                    myService.dataParse(getString(R.string.pause));
                    tv.setText(R.string.resume);
                }else {
                    myService.dataParse(getString(R.string.stop));
                }



            }
        });
```

//Now the problem is while I am playing it is playing fine but wile I am try to pause the app crashes with the following exception.But as the service is running mp3 play on.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.pause()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.riyaghosh.mp3fileservicedownload.MyService.dataParse(MyService.java:58)
                                                                               at com.example.riyaghosh.mp3fileservicedownload.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
```

//I am stuck on it several times.Please provide some solution.

Comment: Your media is null

Comment: return Service instance using `onBind ` method to access `dataParse ` method instead of creating object of class which is extending `Service `

Comment: Can u post some sample code?It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mediaplayer != null) {
    mediaplayer.stop(); 
    mediaplayer.reset();
    mediaplayer.release();
}
```

Comment: Is the link that you have provided even related to the question asked?

Comment: But this is not the ultimate solution.Cause it will prevent the app from exception but wont pause the media player.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void dataParse(String value){
    if(value.equals(R.string.play)){
         if(!media.isPlaying())
           {
        media.start();
           }
    }else  if(value.equals("pause")) {
         if(media.isPlaying())
         {
         media.pause();
         }
    }else {
        if(media.isPlaying())
        {
        media.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

one more thing  you can stop service to pause media and then start service again

```
  stopService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.android.homeworthyinspection.globaldata;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is ;
    JSONObject jObj;
    String json;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
        is = null;
        jObj = null;
        json = "";
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //Log.e("param",params +"");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", ">"+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //          Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }
        return jObj;
    }


    public  String POST(String url, JSONObject person){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            /*jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
            jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
            jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());*/

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = person.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(person.toString());

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }


    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }   


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl1(String url,JSONObject nameValuePairs) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //Log.e("param",params +"");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            /*if(params!=null)*/
            /*httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));*/
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(nameValuePairs.toString(),"UTF-8");

            //sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            //Log.e("JSON", ">"+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("exc at json parser", ""+e);
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //          Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }
        return jObj;
    }


    /*public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url_, JSONObject jsonObject) {

        try {
            URLConnection urlConn;
            DataOutputStream printout;

            URL url = new URL (url_);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setDoInput (true);
            urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
            urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   
            urlConn.connect();
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(300000000);
            Log.e("jsonobject",jsonObject +"");

            printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
            printout.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            printout.flush ();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            printout.close ();
            reader.close();

            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", ">"+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
//          Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }
        return jObj;

    }*/


}
```